# Cannot set custom CurrentSessionContext class in Spring Session Factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to implement a Session-Per-Conversation pattern in a JSF2-Spring-Hibernate Web App so I need my AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to build a Hibernate SessionFactory with a custom CurrentSessionContext class.

I have been receiving this error log:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain Hibernate-managed Session for Spring-managed transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

Here is my xml config for the whole data context used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${datasource.poolInitialSize}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${org.hibernate.dialect.dialectmysqlInno}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${org.hibernate.ddl.mode}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">${org.hibernate.search.directoryprovidr}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                    mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.web.conversation.ConversationalCurrentSessionContext
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateManagedSession" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven order="0" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.dao.hibernate" />

</beans>
```

Also, here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="jgtjoSessionFactory">
        <!--Entity -->
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.AudienciaOral" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.CausaPenal" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.DefensorPenal" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.Delito" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.EventoAudiencia" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.Juez" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.MinisterioPublico" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.ParteMaterial" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.Sala" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.TipoAudiencia" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.User" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.Rol" />
        <mapping class="mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.model.DelitoConfigurado" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As you can see, nothing tricky with hibernate xml.

Why I keep getting this exception?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.web.conversation.ConversationalCurrentSessionContext.<init>(org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor)
```

It seems that hibernate looks for a constructor in my class that has a SessionFactory as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as the anwer above showed me the code and the logging I showed in my question edit the implementation of the CurrentSessionContext interface must have a public constructor with a sessionFactory as argument.

Hibernate docs never say anything like that.

and here is my class:

```
    package mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.web.conversation;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.web.utils.JsfUtils;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ConversationalCurrentSessionContext implements CurrentSessionContext {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 803157986557235023L;

    protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ConversationalCurrentSessionContext.class);

    public ConversationalCurrentSessionContext() {

    }

    @Override
    public Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {

        HttpServletRequest request = null;

        try {
            request = JsfUtils.getCurrentHttpRequest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("No current http request in faces context, returning default conversation.");
        }

        if (request == null) {
            return (Session) ConversationManager.getDefaultConversationSession();
        } else {
            return (Session) ConversationManager.getSessionForRequest(request);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I lack that constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code from Hibernate which attempts to build the current session context using whatever value you passed in using the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property:

```
private CurrentSessionContext buildCurrentSessionContext() {
        String impl = properties.getProperty( Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS );
        // for backward-compatability
        if ( impl == null && transactionManager != null ) {
            impl = "jta";
        }

        if ( impl == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        else if ( "jta".equals( impl ) ) {
            if ( settings.getTransactionFactory().areCallbacksLocalToHibernateTransactions() ) {
                log.warn( "JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()" );
            }
            return new JTASessionContext( this );
        }
        else if ( "thread".equals( impl ) ) {
            return new ThreadLocalSessionContext( this );
        }
        else if ( "managed".equals( impl ) ) {
            return new ManagedSessionContext( this );
        }
        else {
            try {
                Class implClass = ReflectHelper.classForName( impl );
                return ( CurrentSessionContext ) implClass
                        .getConstructor( new Class[] { SessionFactoryImplementor.class } )
                        .newInstance( new Object[] { this } );
            }
            catch( Throwable t ) {
                log.error( "Unable to construct current session context [" + impl + "]", t );
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see acceptable values are `jta`, `thread`, `managed`.

Since you're using Spring's transaction management functionality you shouldn't set this property at all. Spring will take care of this for you.

You just need to annotate your transactional methods with `@Transactional` and a session will be opened and bound to the current thread for you.

Comment: As you can see in Table 3.7. Miscellaneous Properties accepted values are "e.g. jta | thread | managed | custom.Class" and I am passing the class fully qualified name and in the last else you can see how hibernate is making a reflection invocation of my class. And inyecting a session factory by constructor.

Comment: And I cannot answer my own question in 8 hours. LoL. Thank you Jeff.

Comment: Why hibernate docs do not show that the class implementing CurrentSessionContext must have that constructor?

Comment: Not sure! I got this a bit wrong :( Hope the code is useful though.